# Normal Distribution Problem Normal Graph

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

> Maple tree diameters in a forest area are normally distributed with a
>   mean of 10 inches and a standard deviation of 2.5 inches. In a forest
>   of 2000 maple trees, how many would have a diameter greater than 15
>   inches??

I'm having some trouble with this question, if someone could answer in plain English that'll be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $15$inches$-10$inches is two standard deviations since $\sigma=2.5$ inches. Using the 68-95-99 rule tells us that only $5\%$ of all the trees will lie outside of two standard deviations from the mean. Since we are only looking at being bigger than the mean instead of bigger or smaller, that means we cut that $5\%$ number in half to get $2.5\%$. So, $2.5\%$ of the maple trees will be bigger than $15$inches and since there are $n=2000$ trees, that means we expect $50$ to be bigger than $15$inches.